# Why do I get "init: failed to create pty..." errors on boot?

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday with a LiveUSB.
I had problems at booting, so I had to repair grub, and it was ok.
But now when I start up my pc, I get the error message

'init: failed to create pty - disabling logging for job'

And nothing happens. How to fix that?

Comment: I had the same problem after 2 days of upgrade and after normal reboot

Answer (score 6):

This is currently a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/980917) in *upstart* (Ubuntu's startup manager or `init`-replacement).

It should not be happening to normal users running the regular Ubuntu kernel on a desktop/laptop, but apparently it does for some of them.

The fix is to add a `--no-log` boot option to your kernel command line. You can do this by editing `/etc/default/grub`:

- `Alt+F2`, then `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Look for the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`
- The line normally says this:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Add `--no-log` to that line, i.e.:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash --no-log"`
- Save and exit. Reboot and the errors/warnings should be gone.

---

#### Technical Explanation

According to comments in the bug report, upstart expects `/dev/pts` to be mounted and the `/dev/ptmx` device to exist when it starts, and prints these errors when it can't find the devices. These are set up by the initramfs on Ubuntu, so in theory these errors should only occur on embedded devices, etc. that have no initramfs. They should not be fatal because eventually in the startup process, `mountall` will ensure that `/dev/pts` and `/dev/ptmx` are set up correctly.

Comment: the bug is now fixed. sudo aptitude upgrade upstart should apply the fix on your system.