# Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 problem

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “init: failed to create pty…” errors on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126779/why-do-i-get-init-failed-to-create-pty-errors-on-boot)

Hey, I just updated from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 from update manager, and now when I start it up it says :

```
failed to create pyt  - disabling logging for job.
```

I have no idea what to do. Please help.

I'm not a computer geek, so please make instructions easy.

Comment: Check that all updates are added.  Open terminal and type: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**  Answer 'Y', if asked, to proceed with updates.  Then **SHUTDOWN and REBOOT**.  Report back, if you are still having issues ..

Comment: @david6 Since your advice in that comment is intended to solve the problem, I recommend making it an answer.

Comment: Already closed.